# ng-click not working inside datatables

Tags: angularjs, datatable

I've been trying to call editFleet(id) inside a datatable row but unfortunately it's not working. Here the code:

```
angular.module("app").controller('FleetsCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $cookies) {
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'someURL' + $cookies.get("account_id"),
    headers: {
        "x-access-token": $cookies.get("token"),
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    },
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true
}).success(function(data) {
    $("#loading").css('display', 'none');
    $html = "<tr><th width='25%'>Fleet Name</th><th>Assets</th><th>Description</th><th class='no-sort' width='219px'></th></tr>";
    $('#datatables thead').append($html);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.response.length; i++) {
        var fname = data.response[i].name;
        var fdesc = data.response[i].desc;
        var id = data.response[i].fleet_id;
        var asset_count = data.response[i].asset_count;
        $html = "<tr> <td>" + fname + "</td><td width='25%'>" + asset_count + "</td> <td width='25%;'>" + fdesc + "</td> <td style='text-align:right;'> <button title='Edit' data-ng-click='editFleet(" + id + ")' type='button' class='btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></button> <button type='button' onclick='deleteFleet(" + id + ")' class='btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-remove' title='Delete'></button> </td>";
        $('#datatables tbody').append($html);
    }
}).error(function(error) {
    alert("Error");
});

$scope.editFleet = function(id){
    console.log("check");
}
```

});

I do not want to call the function from onclick event like we do in raw js. Is there any way to call the ng-click? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you cannot bind angular function to DOM created via jQuery. This is not the right way to do it. You need to use angular directives for this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response..but can you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I happened to fix the issue but don't know if this is the right way to do it or not but it worked for me.

I used `$compile` before append. Here's the full code to maintain the continuity:

```
angular.module("app").controller('FleetsCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $cookies, $compile) {
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'someURL' + $cookies.get("account_id"),
    headers: {
        "x-access-token": $cookies.get("token"),
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    },
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true
}).success(function(data) {
    $("#loading").css('display', 'none');
    $html = "<tr><th width='25%'>Fleet Name</th><th>Assets</th><th>Description</th><th class='no-sort' width='219px'></th></tr>";
    $('#datatables thead').append($html);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.response.length; i++) {
        var fname = data.response[i].name;
        var fdesc = data.response[i].desc;
        var id = data.response[i].fleet_id;
        var asset_count = data.response[i].asset_count;
        $html = $compile("<tr> <td>" + fname + "</td><td width='25%'>" + asset_count + "</td> <td width='25%;'>" + fdesc + "</td> <td style='text-align:right;'> <button title='Edit' data-ng-click='editFleet(" + id + ")' type='button' class='btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></button> <button type='button' onclick='deleteFleet(" + id + ")' class='btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-remove' title='Delete'></button> </td>")($scope);
        $('#datatables tbody').append($html);
    }
}).error(function(error) {
    alert("Error");
});

$scope.editFleet = function(id){
    console.log("Success");
}
```

});

This works just fine and servers my purpose.

P.S. If this is not the proper way to do it, please post your suggestions and solutions.